# how to update many to many table in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 3 tables:

**News**

```
public partial class News
{
    public News()
    {
        this.Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
    }

    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    public string NewsTitle { get; set; }
    public string NewsBody { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime NewsDate { get; set; }
    public string NewsImagePath { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

**Category**

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.News = new HashSet<News>();
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

and the middle table is NewsCategory which is the Many to many relationship.

I updated the middle table by sending t-sql to database.

Now the question is **How can I update the middle table with LINQ instead of t-sql**

All I want is to replace that code with Linq to do the same function

Here is my code:

```
if (model.SelectedCategoriesIds != null)
{
    string SqlCommandToInsert = string.Empty;
    string SqlCommandToDelete = string.Empty;

    var OriginalCategoriesIds = NewsToUpdate.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryId);

    int[] selectedCategoriesIds = model.SelectedCategoriesIds.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray();

    foreach (var CategoryId in OriginalCategoriesIds)
    {
        if (!selectedCategoriesIds.Contains(CategoryId))
        {
            SqlCommandToDelete += "Delete from NewsCategory where NewsId=" + NewsToUpdate.NewsId + " and CategoryId=" + CategoryId;
        }
    }

    foreach (var SelectedId in selectedCategoriesIds)
    {
        if (!OriginalCategoriesIds.Contains(SelectedId))
        {
            SqlCommandToInsert += "Insert into NewsCategory (NewsId,CategoryId) values(" + NewsToUpdate.NewsId + "," + SelectedId + ")";
        }
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SqlCommandToDelete) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SqlCommandToInsert))
    {
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(SqlCommandToDelete + SqlCommandToInsert);
    }
}
else
{
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Delete from NewsCategory where NewsId=" + NewsToUpdate.NewsId);

}
```

Comment: Take your News object from the DbContext. Make any changes you want to the Categories list, then call DbContext.SaveChanges();

Comment: Thank you for your help ... I tried that it didn't work ... Can you please use my code to show me how can i do that?

Comment: could you show the properties of your Third table? Or is it just the two ID fields?

Comment: @tCoe Yes just two Ids   NewsId and CategoryId

Comment: @Lucia don't worry about the 3rd table, Entity Framework has already mapped that relationship using the virtual ICollection<Category> Categories. Just manipulate the items in that property and save your changes. EF will handle the SQL for your many-to-many table. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make your changes directly to your Entity model, using a DbContext, then save the changes. LINQ to Entity will take care of the SQL statements. This sample below should put you on the right path to getting this to work. You shouldn't have to write any SQL statements.

```
// Replace with your real model from MVC
var model = new Model { SelectedCategoriesIds = new List<int>() };
model.SelectedCategoriesIds.Add(1);
model.SelectedCategoriesIds.Add(2);
model.SelectedCategoriesIds.Add(3);

var newsToUpdate = new News {  Categories = new List<Category>() }; // Replace with your call to database

// Use an Entity Framework context to update our db model
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    // First clear existing categories
    newsToUpdate.Categories.Clear();

    // Now add selected categories
    foreach (var selectedCategory in model.SelectedCategoriesIds)
    {
        var dbCat = dbContext.Categories.Single(c => c.Id == selectedCategory);
        newsToUpdate.Categories.Add(dbCat);
    };

    // Save changes
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to work directly with collections News and Categories. Add or Remove entities for these collections. After that you have to save News and Category entities. For example:

```
        var category = new Category();
        var news = new News();
        var removedNews = new News();
        var newCategory = new Category();

        category.News.Remove(removedNews);
        news.Categories.Add(newCategory);
        //to do save category and news
```